# How to fix JSX expression must have one parent element?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to toggle a Modal in react native. Each item in a flatlist should have a toggle option to open a modal.

I get the error:
JSX expressions must have one parent element.

I have tried to google for the right syntax but can't find a solution.

```
class CategoriesScreen extends Component {

  state = {
    modalVisible: false,
  };

  setModalVisible(visible) {
    this.setState({ modalVisible: visible });
  }

  render() {
function Item({ title }) {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.item} onPress={() => {
          this.setModalVisible(true);
        }}>
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity> 
        <Modal
          animationType="slide"
          transparent={false}
          visible={this.state.modalVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => {
            Alert.alert('Modal has been closed.');
          }}>
          <View style={{ marginTop: 22 }}>
            <View>
              <Text>Hello World!</Text>

              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                  this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible);
                }}>
                <Text>Hide Modal</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
        </Modal>
    };
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.heading}>Select a category for daily tasks.</Text>
        <Text style={styles.subheading}>{`You will receive a daily task in this category.\nLet’s get consistent!`}</Text>
        <FlatList
          data={DATA}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item.title} />}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          numColumns={2}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

I am trying to get open one unique modal for each item in the flatlist.

Comment: If you are looking for unique modals, then I would just having unique state variables for managing each of them. You can't manage all the modals with a common state variable. You can have an attribute inside a flatlist object which manages the state of the modal.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can only return a single entity. To fix this just surround your return in your `Item` function with a [`<Fragment/>`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) element (from the `react` package).

> Fragments let you group a list of children without adding extra nodes to the DOM.

This can be done like so:

```
import React, {Fragment} from 'react';
... 
function Item({ title }) {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.item} onPress={() => {
          this.setModalVisible(true);
        }}>
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity> 
        <Modal
          animationType="slide"
          transparent={false}
          visible={this.state.modalVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => {
            Alert.alert('Modal has been closed.');
          }}>
          <View style={{ marginTop: 22 }}>
            <View>
              <Text>Hello World!</Text>

              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                  this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible);
                }}>
                <Text>Hide Modal</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
        </Modal>
      </Fragment>
   )
};
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: You can also use the shorthand `<></>` as well.

Comment: @woat I believe you need a babel plugin for that still, no?

Comment: This fixed the error but instead I get this error now: TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.modalVisible')

Comment: Ahh I see. I believe you need a constructor. and set your state object inside of it instead of were it currently is like so: `constructor(props){ super(props); this.state = { modalVisible: false, }; }`

Comment: @MiroslavGlamuzina Thank you :) I am trying, not sure where to put it?

Comment: No problem. It will go right underneath this line -> `class CategoriesScreen extends Component {`. (don't forget to remove `state = {modalVisible: false};` (this will be in the constructor like the snippet  I last sent)

Comment: Great! I added it like this.

```react-native
class CategoriesScreen extends Component {

  constructor(props){ super(props); this.state = { modalVisible: false, }; }
```

I still have the problem: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.modalVisible')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201176/discussion-between-9minday-and-miroslav-glamuzina).